# Express $f(x,n+1)$ rationally in terms of $f(x,n)$ and $x,$ and evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x,n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, contest-math

The question is taken from [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxudHVtYXRoY29tcGV0aXRpb25zfGd4OjYzN2NiMDBlOWUyZWI2ZTU) Exercise $5$:$

> **Question:** Consider the function 
>       $$f(x,n) = \frac{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{2}x + \binom{n}{4}x^2 + \dots}{\binom{n}{1} +\binom{n}{3}x + \binom{n}{5}x^2+\dots} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{2k}x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{2k+1}x^k},$$
>       where $n$ is a positive integer. 
>       Express $f(x,n+1)$ rationally in terms of $f(x,n)$ and $x.$
>       Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x,n)$ for suitable fixed values of $x.$

My attempt:

I tried to evaluate $f(x,n+1)$ directly. However, the hindrance is the combination $\binom{n}{k}$ formula and infinite summation $\sum$.

In the first place, i was thinking of swapping $\binom{n}{k}$ and $\sum,$ just like some analysis questions, whereby swapping is allowed if certain conditions are fulfilled.
However, this does not make sense.

Any hint to solve both parts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$${n+1\choose k}={n\choose k}+{n\choose k-1}$$
Hence the numerator of $f(x,n+1)$ is numerator of $f(x,n)$ plus $x$ times denominator of $f(x,n)$, and the denominator of $f(x,n+1)$ is just the sum of numerator and denominator of $f(x,n)$.
So you want to express $\frac{A+xB}{A+B}$ in terms  of $\frac AB$ and $x$.